# Why does it take so long for the support class to re-supply rockets/mines/etc?

Tags: battlefield-3

It seems like there is a lag between when rockets/mines/c4/etc gets reloaded compared to bullets by the support guy dropping ammo.  Is that the case or am I imagining it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not imagining, it takes longer to resupply explosives (including grenades). I'm pretty sure the reason is game balance, since these weapons inflict quite a lot of damage and too fast resupply would make players with these weapons too powerfull.

Comment: not only that, but I believe explosive resupply "uses up" the supply crate faster too at which point it disappears. So the support guy will need to drop another supply crate even faster!

Comment: are there numbers for how long it takes for different ammo types?

Comment: It's also kind of prioritized, ie. you will only start getting grenades, after you're fully re-stocked with guns' ammo.

Comment: Vartec: are you sure that isn't just an effect of grenades taking longer?

Comment: @MichaelPryor I don't think anyone has documented this. But anecdotally I have noticed that regular gun ammo has to fill first before explosives will even *begin* to fill. So the supply crate can used up on just rifle ammo .. it is possible, because that always goes first.

Comment: @JeffAtwood how do you know when the supply crate gets used up? does it just disappear?

Comment: @MichaelPryor that is correct. It does seem as though primary bullets (then secondary bullets) are prioritized over explosives when resupplying